# Wordpress sidebar doesn't load on product attributes archive woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, sidebar

I am building an e-commerce store on Wordpress using Woocommerce.

I have created a sidebar with filters etc. that work fine on normal category and shop archives.

Working sidebar image

[image].

The problem is that when I go to an attributes archive (e.g. /brand/xxxx) the sidebar does not load.

Not working sidebar image

[image].

I have tried creating a product attribute template in the `/woocommerce` directory by creating a `taxonomy-pa_brand.php` file but that did not fix it.

Comment: I suggest sharing some code...